# How can I Read multiple JSON files through Angular Resources Service?

Tags: angularjs, resources

Here, I got my module like:

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', [ngResource]);
```

then I have my service like this:

```
eventsApp.factory('listData', function($resource){
   return $resource('/data/event/:eventid', {}, {
       'update': {method:'PUT'},
       'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
   });
});
```

And as well in my controller, I have:

```
eventsApp.controller('EventListController', 
    function EventListController($scope, listData) {
        $scope.events = listData.query();
    }
);
```

Then I use *ngRepeat* in order to go through the data I got back from *$resource*, like:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events"> do sth..</li>
```

As in my directory "/data/event", I have several JSON files named 1, 2, 3, 4. Give 1 a shot:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Angular Boot Camp",
    "date": "1/1/2013",
    "time": "13:40 pm",
    "creator":"bob",
    "location":{
        "address": "Google HQ",
        "city": "Mountain View",
        "province": "CA"
    },
    "imageUrl": "/img/angularjs-logo.jpg"
}
```

What I want to do is to get all the four files back into an array of objects using *$resource.query()*, but it seems like I have to set up my web-server or something?

Comment: Are you using a database at all? It sounds like you just have files on disk - is that right? If so then you need some server side logic that responds to a url and concats all the files into a single response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through one day endeavor, finally, I got another server set up to be *RESTful*. And actually, the essential issue lying under is that: my file names. Since I use Windows 8, it is kind of like without a postfix file type, so in my directory originally there are files named just *"1" & "2"*, of course this is not gonna work, and I didn't realize it. Fortunately, when I accounted into another demo and got the same issue, in any minute, I change the file name to *"1.json", "2.json"*. Magically, it works. Thx. Close of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you need to setup the server and set the eventid to @id.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

```
eventsApp.factory('listData', function($resource){
   return $resource('/data/event/:eventid', {eventid: '@id'}, {});
});
```

Comment: The question is how to set up my server. Actually I am using node.js. And for this question, I don't see any difference to set the eventid to '@id', because query() is not get(), which needs @id setting.